# How can I update computed from method in vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

My component vue like this :

```
<template>
    <div>
        <ul class="list-inline list-photo">
            <li v-for="item in items">
                <template v-if="photoList[item]">
                    ...
                        <img :src="baseUrl+'/img/products/thumbs/'+photo(item)">
                    ...
                </template>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['product'],
        data() {
                return {
                    items: [1,2,3,4,5],
                    baseUrl: window.Laravel.baseUrl,
                    photoList: this.product.photo_list.reduce(function(acc, p) { acc[Number(p.id)] = p; return acc;}, {}),
                }
        },
        computed: {
            photo(item) {
                return (this.photoList) ? photoList[item].name : ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            createImage(item, response) {
                ...
                this.photo(item) = photoAdded.name
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

If the createImage method is executed, I want to update the photo on a computed with a value of photoAdded.name.

Whether it can be done?

Comment: Computed properties are getter-only by default and you can not pass arguments to them like so, instead you can either adopt another approach, for ex. use methods, or define setter for that computed property. Read [this documentation page](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter) for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computed properties are defined as *no-argument* functions, but you access them as a property. They're not methods, so `this.photo(item)` won't work. It looks like you meant for `photo` to be a method, not a computed property:

```js
methods: {
    photo(item) {
        return (this.photoList) ? this.photoList[item].name : ''
    }
}
```

You can only assign to a variable or a property, not the return value of a method like `this.photo(item) = photoAdded.name`.

Try doing this:

```js
createImage(item, response) {
    ...

    this.photoList[item].name = photoAdded.name
    // OR
    this.photoList[item] = photoAdded
}
```

---

Your data model could probably be simplified. Why is `items` an array of integers? Do you even need `items`? Why not just loop over each photo like this:

```html
<li v-for="photo in photoList">
    ...
    <img :src="baseUrl + '/img/products/thumbs/' + photo.name">
    ...
</li>
```

(I can only speculate based on the code you have provided, so you might have a valid reason for doing it a certain way.)